# Help write a book review, please

Tags: reviews

**Edited** to incorporate @Craig Sefton's [suggestions](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/2506/26).

About a book that I admire, I wrote in an SE computer-programming group:

> The material seems old -- well, it *is* old -- because it's been around for long and, while by no means trivial, is well understood. A solution you can lift is published in W. Richard Stevens's superb and unparalleled book (read "bible"),  [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, Second Edition](http://tinyurl.com/6eoufdc). **The book is the rare treasure that's clear, concise, and complete; its every page gives real, immediate value.**

In the emboldened phrase, I want to convey that the book is in contrast to other 1200-page doorstops because it has no fluff, no extraneous or off-topic matter. Almost every other programming book should be of 256 pages; this book justifies its length on every page. So:

- Should I even try to include that idea? Maybe I should just let the contrast go and talk about the book itself.

  If so, how can I do it concisely? I'm afraid that too many words will bore the reader and weaken the contrast.

Comment: this is a great example of what a critique question *should* be: specific!

Comment: @NeilFein what's with all the sudden edits to old questions?

Comment: @NeilFein Oh are you reviving a ton of critique-type questions for some reason?

Comment: @NeilFein OH you got rid of the Critique tag. Okay. I'll stop now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you've already used the word I would use in your question: concise. I would also perhaps split the overall sentence into two lines. A possible suggestion:

> A solution you can lift is published
>   in W. Richard Stevens's superb and
>   unparalleled book (read "bible"),
>   Advanced Programming in the UNIX
>   Environment, Second Edition. It is one
>   of those rare books that is clear and
>   concise, which gives every page real
>   and immediate value.

**Edit:** Based on the update to the question, I think including the idea is necessary. Concise and clear programming books are invaluable, so that's a big strength. Don't worry about boring the reader; you'll only do that if your review isn't ... umm ... clear and concise. Oh, and I would probably drop either tangible, or real, since they essentially mean the same thing (I've edited my recommendation above to reflect this).

Comment: @CS -- yes, that's right, thanks. I'll edit the Q to incorporate your good idea.

Comment: @CS -- right, ditto.

Comment: @CS -- the "tangible" was there just for scansion, anway, so to dump that word is an improvement.

Comment: @Pete Wilson - Not sure about the usage of "correct"; it seems redundant. If the book was incorrect, it wouldn't be such a good resource. This could work: The book is one of those rare treasures that is clear, concise, and complete, giving every page real and immediate value.

Comment: @Craig Sefton -- Thanks. And now I'll give the thing a rest until later. I'll take another look then.

Comment: remove "The book is one of those rare treasures", insert "The book is the rare treasure". There's a formal name for this sort of thing, but I've forgotten what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I really like your 1200-page doorstop comment. That's not boring, and it's evocative.

Can you use that?

> This is a big book, but unlike
>   1200-page doorstops, this book
>   justifies its length. It is the rare
>   treasure that's clear, concise, and
>   complete; its every page gives real,
>   immediate value.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to work that figure in. Maybe "10-pound" is better than "1200-page." What do you think?

Comment: I'd probably stick with page count, but either is good. :)